# How to configure StatisticsCsvLayout in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, perf4j

Need help from migrating log4j to log4j2. I have a rollingFileAppender. I need this appender to make use of "StatisticsCsvLayout" in org.perf4j. Previously in log4j 1.x version we used to directly refer the StatisticsCsvLayout from any appender using following tag in log4j.xml.

```
<Layout class='org.perf4j.log4j.StatisticsCsvLayout'/>
```

We are unable to confire this from log4j2.xml as we are not able to make use of external layouts directly. Please tell me how to configure this in log4j2.xml.

Comment: What did you mean when you say: «*there is no provision to make use of external layouts directly*»?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the org.perf4j StatisticsCsvLayout is not directly compatible with log4j2, you may need to create your own (or convince the perf4j people to port this layout to log4j2).
Fortunately creating a custom layout is not very difficult. Here is some sample code. You can also look at the log4j2 source code for more details, like how to pass parameters.

[link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-943?jql=project%20%3D%20LOG4J2)

Thanks to @Remko Popma for the help. :)